# How do I make an bash script based on this?

Tags: linux, bash

When I run this command it shows all the inactive users in this format
`user:INACTIVE`. I only want to print out the users with greater than 30 days or empty "".

```sh
grep -E ^[^:]+:[^\!*] /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,7
```

This is my attempt however it only outputs root.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if users = ( $(awk -F '$7 > 30 || $7 == "" {print $1" " $7;rc=1}END{exit !rc}' /etc/shadow) )
then
   echo $users
fi
```

Comment: Your bash script is syntactically incorrect: there are no spaces around the `=` assignment operator and if you want to print all elements of the `user` array you cannot just use `$user`.  Try `echo "${user[@]}"` or, much better, `printf '%s\n' "${user[@]}"`. Finally, you probably forgot to specify the `awk` field separator: `awk -F:`, not `awk -F`.

Comment: I would like to print out 2 fields which are user and inactive days. The first command does that but I only want the users who have greater than 30 inactive days and empty string. That is what I am trying to achieve on my second one. 

So for example the output that I would like to see is:
root:"" 
test2:50

Comment: OK, see my answer, if I am not wrong it should be about what you want.

Comment: Your attempt looks like `grep` to `awk` and not `grep` to `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not just put your initial command into a bash file?

It's works on wsl Debian. What system are you using?

Comment: CENTOS. How do I turn it into a script? I am a newbie and just trying to attempt it.

Comment: Copy it into a text file called script.sh and make it executable:(chmod 700 script.sh) and then run it with ./script.sh The name isn't important : use something meaningful for you.

Comment: I only want to print all the users which has greater than 30 days or empty "". The first command prints out everything

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

awk -F: '$2 != "*" && ($7+0 > 30 || $7 == "") {print $1 ":" $7}' /etc/shadow
```

Comment: Hi sorry I think I left out something. Your code works but I only need the users which have passwords.

Comment: Please edit your question and add this important information such that other SO users have all elements. I added this test to my answer.

Comment: It doesn't print out like the first one where it prints only root and one other account called test2 with 50 days inactivity

Comment: Here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/OtCJQQH

Comment: There is only one way to solve this kind of mismatches between your expectations and the answers you get: create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, an example input file and the expected corresponding output. Try to create a representative input example that more or less covers all possibilities. And of course, please do this by editing your question.